# References in same solution in .NET and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference

I need you guys to finally arrange this issue well in my head.

As an example, my solution contains two projects:

Project 1 has a reference to the Moq class library.

Project 2 (which is a unit test project) has a reference to Project 1.

Both needs to utilize Moq classes directly.

Does Project 2 need to have a reference to the Moq class library as well?

What if Project 1 has a static method MethodX which utilize a Moq method and returns a non Moq class library based type, and Project 2 needs to run MethodX? Should Project 2 still need a reference to the Moq class library?

Thanks,

Mikey

Comment: I'm scared to ask why the non-test project has a reference to Moq?

Comment: LOL, obviously it does not, it was just for the example's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project 2 needs reference to the Moq library **only if** this projects have direct access to objects declared in library through Project 1.

Otherwise, if Project 1 isolates Moq's classes, types, structs and uses them for internal purposes only - the reference is not needed.

Comment: But you might need to copy Moq in project2 outputDir ?

Comment: No, VS can resolve such dependencies and put all needed binaries to output directory.